# Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, foreach

I have this simple MVC 4 code. I querying the database and getting all the results, saving then in a ViewBag object and then looping through them with a foreach but the an error:

> Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type

does not let me show them. What im missing?

Here the sql query with entityframework

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var ReturnLabelsAndInputsForIndexations = Conexion.MainConexion;

    var IndexationForm = ReturnLabelsAndInputsForIndexations.Labels.ToList();
    ViewBag.IndexationForm = IndexationForm;

    return View();
}
```

And the index View

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <table>
        @foreach (var Indexacion_Labels in ViewBag.IndexationForm)
        { 
            <tr>
                <td>@Indexacion_Labels["LABELS"]//Exception HERE</td>
                <td>@GetInputType(Indexacion_Labels["INPUT_TYPE"], Indexacion_Labels["NAME"])</td>
            </tr>
        }
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ff926074.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of `ReturnLabelsAndInputsForIndexations.Labels` (whatever type that is) does not implement an [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6x16t2tx.aspx). To resolve this you would either need to add this to the view model for labels

```
public this[string index]
{
    get
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

*OR* change your view code to something like this (assuming the properties of the view model exist)

```
<tr>
    <td>@Indexacion_Labels.Labels</td>
    <td>@GetInputType(Indexacion_Labels.Input_Type, Indexacion_Labels.Name)</td>
</tr>
```